# Keep only the latest version of elements in a list

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
x = c("123-1", "123-2", "123-3", "222-1", "222-2", "333-1")
```

but it is very big.

I want to only keep the latest version of each number. So I want output as below:

```
z=c("123-3", "222-2", "333-1")
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Parse the array in order and put them in a hash-map(key-value store) where the key is the number and the value is the number with -. This way it will always overwrite the old values for similar numbers. Then call .values on the hashmap and you have your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your `x` is actually strings

```
x = c("123-1", "123-2", "123-3", "222-1", "222-2", "333-1")

x[!duplicated(sapply(strsplit(x, "-"), '[', 1), fromLast = TRUE)]
#[1] "123-3" "222-2" "333-1"
```

Comment: it works thank you. can i ask.. what does this '[', 1), fromLast = TRUE)] part of the code actually do?

Comment: A little cleaner with `sub` instead of `strsplit`: `x[!duplicated(sub("-\\d$", "", x), fromLast = TRUE)]`, which avoids `sapply` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether the strings are always in order.  If not, then we may need to `order` it

```
unname(tapply(x, sub("-.*", ".", x), FUN = function(y) 
                           y[order(-as.numeric(sub("-", ".", y)))][1]))
#[1] "123-3" "222-2" "333-1"
```